# Is there any way for LaTeX to provide a file context for better log messages?

Tags: packages, external-files, logging

## UPDATE: In hindsight, I realize that this question is really, "Is there any way for LaTeX to keep the file context and warning/error message on the same line?"

This would be fore the purpose of automated parsing of a log file using regular expressions *(e.g. looking for a key word like "Invalid" and having the file context be in the result, not just the one line containing the message).*

egreg answered this with a definitive NO, it is hardcoded in XeTeX. :(

## UPDATE 2016-05-19

In an e-mail to the maintainer of `anyfontsize` P. Szabó:

> I'm not actively maintaining this package anymore. Feel free to convert it to UTF-8, and upload the new version of CTAN. You have my approval.

---

## Original question text

I am typesetting documents with XeLaTeX. I have the bold aspiration to remove all warnings and errors from my document builds :D *(nearly impossible, but nothing I cannot strive for!)*

One of the warnings I and a colleague finally tracked down to `anyfontsize`, which is an official package in TeX Live. All packages are either in UTF-8 or ASCII, except this one (ISO-8859), because the creator has diacritics in his name (likely Hungarian ;) ) I e-mailed him about this already. Anyway, **my real concern is the following  message**:

`grep -Pin 'Invalid' myfile.log`

> Invalid UTF-8 byte or sequence at line 3 replaced by U+FFFD.

This message is useless without a context (yes, line 3 is a context, but hardly useful as you can see). I propose adding context to these messages by adding the file name. This way, I could immediately know that this error was cause during the reading of `anyfontsize`.  Maybe something like "show last file loaded" before every error/warning.

Is this already possible? I know about `\listfiles`, which is great!

I can try to suppress messages that are not a problem by using the [`silence` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/silence). However, it is not a good idea to do this, because the message is not unique enough without a context (line 3 of what?).

Comment: I don't think this package can really raise that error, because the accented letters in the 8 bit encoding are commented. Any MWE?

Comment: But the context is there. You only need to look one line up.

Comment: @egreg: It is the package. xetex complains also about 8bit in comments.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer No it is not. line 3 refers to line 3 of the package, not of my document (I only know that after exhaustive research). And besides that, it would also be useless with other includes that I might have.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I get no error

Comment: The log always tells you which file it currently reads, and the line number always refers to this line.

Comment: @egreg it is not an error, only a silent message in the log-file

Comment: Do you even need package `anyfontsize` with XeLaTeX and `fontspec`?

Comment: You just get an internal warning in the log file; nothing to be worried about. And nothing you can silence unless you go and change the `.sty` file. And I don't think you need `anyfontsize` to begin with.

Comment: And to answer your question: the message is a message from the xetex engine and is issued very early while processing/reading the file. Latex can't do anything about it.

Comment: This behaviour of XeTeX on inputting files does not seem to be documented in `xetex-reference.pdf`.

Comment: @Johannes_B Thank you for the `anyfontsize` tip (and egreg). I successfully removed it from all branches of my documentation system without any problems. This was not really the point of the question--just one example of a log message with the file context on another line. It is nice though that by asking questions here, the community helps me to optimize other aspects of my code. Thanks for the support everyone!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you compile with XeLaTeX the following document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}

\begin{document}

aaa

\end{document}
```

your log file will contain

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/anyfontsize/anyfontsize.sty
Invalid UTF-8 byte or sequence at line 3 replaced by U+FFFD.
Invalid UTF-8 byte or sequence at line 3 replaced by U+FFFD.
Package: anyfontsize 2007/11/22 anyfontsize.sty by pts
)
```

that's pretty self explanatory: (Xe)TeX has opened `anyfontsize.sty` and found the bad byte sequences on line 3.

Solution: none. Either you change the `.sty` yourself or the author does it. The message ***cannot*** be silenced.

On the other hand, `anyfontsize` does nothing useful when `fontspec` is loaded. It does little useful, in general, frankly speaking.

Comment: What is the alternative to `\fontsize{20}{25}\selectfont Hello` using only `fontspec`?

Comment: @macmadness86 The alternative is `\fontsize{20}{25}\selectfont`: where is the problem?

Comment: Ah, you mean that `fontspec` loads this functionality or has equivalent functionality? If it loads `anyfontsize`, then won't the message persist?

Comment: @macmadness86 I mean that you don't need `anyfontsize` at all. You're starting from a false premise. If you want to use the Computer Modern fonts at any size, load `fix-cm`. There are *some* fonts that still have `.fd` files with fixed sizes; in that case it's usually very easy to overcome the limitation.

Comment: Anyway, back to the question. Is there anyway to consolidate the log output onto one line, such that my log parser's regular expression 'Invalid' grabs the entire line with the file anyfontsize.sty?

Comment: @macmadness86 Did you even *try* without `anyfontsize`? There is absolutely no need for it in your case.

Comment: Respectfully, this is moving away from the question about proper logging in LaTeX. I'd like consolidate log messages and their contexts onto one line (instead of the multi line output currently). Is this possible? Like I said, I'll investigate what you suggest with `anyfontsize` further.

Comment: @macmadness86 *You can't* change that message in any way; it's hard coded in XeTeX, as I said in my answer.

Comment: @macmadness86 *How can i change the fixed log-message to something different so my parser works* is quite different from *How can i make my parser show the full log message*. I know which question is easier to answer.

Comment: Since a help message can be one line, two line, or five lines long, looking at the log-file with your eyes parsing the relevant bits with your brain seems the most reliable thing to do.